# Separate joined objects

Tags: animation, objects

[image]I'm trying to make a small animation for chemistry, and I'm wondering if you could separate once joined spheres (as a molecule) again. Or is there another way handling this problem?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Do you mean you want to animate the objects coming apart or that you have joined meshes which you wish to separate into individual objects so that you can animate them? Either way, images your what you have will be helpful.

Comment: @RayMairlot How to separate joined objects whose meshes are merging

Comment: As I said images will help. You can add images by using the [edit] link under your question. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @RayMairlot Sorry, it took a while, because I had problems with uploading it. My question is just whether it is possible to separate to joined meshes like above to their original form.

Comment: If the meshes share no common vertices, enter edit mode and press **P** to *separate*, and select Separate by loose parts.

Comment: You can select a vertex of one of them. Ctrl+L to select linked vertices, then P to separate selection. But what is unclear is the context

Comment: As far as i know, having more objects in the scene affects performance. (My pc is not very good). So i try reducing the number of objects, but sometimes I have to separate them later on.

Comment: Well, concerning performance, either you have *many* spheres like that and probably you should lower their vertices or if not that won't make so much difference, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta balls may be useful for you, as they automatically combine two separate objects into one. The individual objects location is all that needs to be animated.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change the transition of the 2 balls? So that they have clear defined boundaries?

Comment: Yes, if you go to the data settings, you can change the defined boundaries threshold

Answer (score 1):

To separate the joined objects, go to edit mode and select all the vertices of object you want to separate. Then, hit <kbd>p</kbd> and click, "selection."
[image]

Comment: Not very helpful, as selecting every single vertice would be very time consuming.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser You only have to select one vertex and then press Ctrl+L.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser This is a very common way of doing it. It's actually helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to make an animaton of the spheres moving away from each other, and there's two ways to do this that I know of.

The first way is to separate them into two different objects by using 'p' and clicking 'Seperate by lose parts'. Then, animate then individually moving away from each other.

The second way would be to use shape keys. This method keeps them as a single object, but lets you animate them to move away from each other. To do this, go to the 'Shape key' tab.

[image]

Click the plus to add a shape key. It should automatically be named 'Basis'.

Move both spheres away from each other and thier starting locations in the 3d viewport.

Click the plus again to add another shape key for the object. This time, it should be called 'Key One'. If done correcly, dragging the slider will cause the spheres to move between thier starting point, 'Basis' and thier end point, 'Key 1'. Now, you can animate the position of the spheres using keyframes and the slider.

Comment: please use the tools provided by the site to add images, so that they are visible as part of the post and not as an external link. If the link goes down then the answer will not be as useful. Please read: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time, thanks.